# php write a file on a different server

Tags: php, file, authentication, directory, cifs

I have a php project on a server ('server A') where I have a form that generate pdf files from a mysql database and all works good!

For some space problems I have to change the path of writing the pdf files on another server ('server B').

The server 'B' is accessible from server 'A' (in windows folder navigation system) but require username and password.

My question is: if the basepath of my project is on a server (server 'A') is there a way to access a remote folder on another server (on server 'B') through php code for writing?

Alternative: Is possibile to copy a file from server 'A' to server 'B'?

Thanks

I tried to write a file on the remote path with fopen function and path like '\\server b\folder1\folder2\file.txt" but don't work

Comment: It won't work unless the user your PHP script runs as has permissions to write to the fileshare path. If it isn't possible to grant such permissions, other alternatives might be to set up FTP or SFTP on server B so that the file can be transmitted by one of those protocols.

Comment: I agree with ADyson: (S)FTP would work. However, you can also post the PDF to server B over the HTTPS protocol. Server B then needs a PHP script that would receive the file and store it. The end result is the same.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes that's another alternative, definitely. Depends what the OP is able to have installed on each server, I guess.